# Android Firebase Authentication not working

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

For my Android application, I'm trying to use Firebase to authentication and data storage. Right now, I'm stuck on authentication. When my application loads, an error stacktrace appears in the Android Studio console.

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Cannot find Google Play services package name.
>
> android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms
>
> at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:137)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzrt.getPackageInfo(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzby(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzbx(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzbs(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.zzc.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqh$zzc.connect(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqh$zzc.zza(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqh.zza(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqh.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

And when I try to submit my email and password credentials, the following messages appear.

> 07-07 14:19:45.330 7430-7449/com.tech_centric.developmentworkflowfirebase W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>
> 07-07 14:19:45.330 7430-7449/com.tech_centric.developmentworkflowfirebase W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.

My project/build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my project/app/build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tech_centric.developmentworkflowfirebase"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Is there something that I'm missing to make this work?

Comment: Do you launch the app on the emulator or on an actual device? Are the google play services installed on the target?

Comment: @dthulke I'm launching the app on the emulator. How do I check if the google play services are installed on the emulator?

Comment: @dthulke I got it installed, but now it's giving me a new error.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 9256000 but found 9080480

Comment: There are currently no emulator images that support 9.2.0.  You either need to downgrade to 9.0.2 or run on a real device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I am not sure if you have imported the generated ***google-services.json*** file in the ***app/*** folder of your project. If you didn't, follow this link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup in section "Add Firebase to your app".
- If it still shows you the error, you can try editing the dependencies in the ***build.gradle*** file in your ***app/*** folder as following:  ***compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'*** to  ***compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2' 
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'***

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes. I placed the google-services.json file in the app/ folder. I'll try down grading the firebase dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when I was running the app using the virtual machine Genymotion API 21. The solution for my problem is to install (add) google play service into the virtual machine Genymotion. The file zip can be downloaded from this link [ARM Translation Installer v1.1](https://filetrip.net/dl?4SUOrdcMRv)  and google play service [Android version 5.0](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95784891001614559). To install Google Play Service just drag and drop both zip files into the home screen of Android Genymotion emulator and reboot the emulator by running `adb reboot` or by clicking the power button of the Android Genymotion emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are missing enabling the `SIGN-IN-METHOD` under Authentication.
Here is screenshot, after enabling the method you will not get this error.
[image]

Now try uploading files on storage, now it will work.

Comment: I did have authentication enabled, so clearly this isn't the error you get when your authentication method isn't enabled.